Circle Theorem Problem - Find Angle BCD
I got into my hands this problem that should be solved using the circle theorems. I think I am rusty with this topic, so I need some help.
I found out many of the angles, except for the angle BCD or any way to get there.
There are 3 given angles:

EDF = 15 degrees
BAH = 70 degrees
FOB = 180 degrees


What I have done so far:

Please help!
EDIT: New info from the person who gave me the picture: AB and ED are parallel!

$\angle BCD$ is not fixed, it depends on point D. You have to tell where D is located. Point E is fixed, it subtends $30^\circ$ at the center. But in your diagram D can lie anywhere on the major arc EF.

Thanks for the replying.  You are right on that. But I asked the person gave me this problem and he forgot to tell me that AB and ED are parallels. That would fix D, right?

There is no answer for this question as d can lie anywhere on the arc ef and there is no specific condition on d
We can define bcd as 180⁰-dfb, but as d is not fixed by any condition dfb will vary causing dcb to vary. Therefore there is no answer to question

Thank you for your response. You are right on that observation! I asked the person who show me this diagram, he told me one more thing I didn't know: AB and ED are parallel!  I think that fixes point D.

Join $EB$.

Since $\angle HAO=90^o$, and $\angle HAB=70^o$, then$$\angle OBA=\angle BAO=20^o$$And since $\angle EBF=\angle EDF=15^o$, then$$\angle BED=\angle EBA=35^o$$Therefore, in cyclic quadrilateral BEDC$$\angle DCB=180^o-35^o=145^o$$

After getting this new information (AB and ED are parallel), I reached this answer:

∠
B
C
D
 is 145 degrees.
. I hope I'm right.


There is another simple angle chasing.
By Tangent Secant Theorem we can say that angle FBA is equal to angle FAG which is equal to 20⁰. By angles inscribed in the circle are same we can get that angle FBA is equal to angle FDA which is equal to 20⁰. Adding angle EDF and angle FDA gives us 35⁰. As ED is parallel to AB then angle DAB is equal to angle EDA which is equal to 35⁰. As we know angle BCD is 180⁰-angle BAD, which gives us that DCB is equal to 145⁰
